# Adding custom (text) entries to GeoTIFF header

Tags: geotiff-tiff, file-formats, cloud-optimized-geotiff

After processing a GeoTIFF, I want to include a note in the output GeoTIFF's header<sup>1</sup>. A keyword-value note like: "`comment` = `image processed with software version x.y.z`". Like we do with FITS files (https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/usage/headers.html#comment-history-and-blank-keywords) in astronomy.

Is that possible with GeoTIFF? If not, which GIS-compatible file format would allow me to do so?

> 1. A file's **header**: metadata information about the file's content (i.e, data) encapsulated in the file itself (typically at the beggining of the file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TIFF has tags for that purpose and you can edit them for example with gdal_edit https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html

> -mo META-TAG=VALUE
>
> Passes a metadata key and value to set on the output dataset if
> possible. This metadata is added to the existing metadata items,
> unless -unsetmd is also specified.

Example:

```
gdal_edit metadata.tif -mo "comment=image processed with software version x.y.z"
```

Check the result with gdalinfo

```
gdalinfo metadata.tif
...
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  comment=image processed with software version x.y.z
...
```